# JSON POST to Sharepoint Using Graph Status Code 400

Tags: c#, json, post, uwp, sharepoint-online

OK.  So this is really starting to baffle me now.  I can get this to work on one UWP app, but not this one.

I have this piece of code to post:

```
public async Task<string> SubmitDataWithTokenAsync(string url, string token)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            try
            {
                var root = new
                {
                    fields = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                       //General Parameters...
                       //Inspection Parameters...
                       //Startup Parameters...
                       //Mechanical Parameters...
                       //Electrical Parameters...
                       //SCR Parameters...
                       //Shutdown Parameters...
                    }
                };

                var s = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat };
                var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, s);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                //Add the token in Authorization header
                request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                request.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

the content comes back just fine, so it seems....

```
"{\"fields\":{\"Date\":\"8/16/2018 2:18:48 PM -04:00\",\"Maximo\":null,\"IBX\":\"DC4\",\"Generator\":\"Generator D\",\"AirQuality\":\"Red / Unhealthy\",\"Engineer\":\"Kassim Ganiyou\",\"MT1Level\":null,\"MT2Level\":null,\"StartDTLevel\":null,\"BC1V\":null,\"BC1A\":null,\"BC2V\":null,\"BC2A\":null,\"StartCoolantTEmp\":null,\"StartHours\":null,\"Reason\":null,\"InspectionNotes\":null,\"StartTime\":null,\"CrankV1\":null,\"CrankV2\":null,\"Emissions\":null,\"SCRStartTime\":null,\"OilPressure\":null,\"CoolantTemp\":null,\"BatteryVolt\":null,\"LeftExhTemp\":null,\"RightExhTemp\":null,\"ABVolts\":null,\"BCVolts\":null,\"CAVolts\":null,\"AAmps\":null,\"BAmps\":null,\"CAmps\":null,\"KW\":null,\"Frequency\":null,\"SCROutletTemp\":null,\"NOx\":null,\"UReaFLow\":null,\"Alarms\":null,\"SCRSTopTime\":null,\"StopTime\":null,\"StopHours\":null}}"
```

The request comes back:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/A07CEC93-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-0F756D2EF63A/items', Version: 2.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eX...PUQ
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 603
}}
```

But then the response is:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  client-request-id: bb26e6fe-4fae-41ae-921d-aeb39063bd8e
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  request-id: bb26e6fe-4fae-41ae-921d-aeb39063bd8e
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"East US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"EUS"}}
  Duration: 319.5961
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Thu, 16 Aug 2018 20:03:10 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
}}
```

I have another UWP app going to the same sharepoint site and I get a Status 201 no problem.  I am just not seeing where my issue is in this case.

Comment: Did you mean the same code in your another project work well, but copy it into this project, it did not work?

Comment: Correct.  I worked on another project to get the concepts down, and when I transferred what I learned from that project to this project I ended up with this error.  I know the client ID is correct and the signon works, but when it comes time to POST the data, I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why it is good to take a break from a project and come back to it later.

I found out that I had mistyped ONE letter on the SharePoint list.  So today when I reviewed the response code it pointed it our to me.

The code WAS good.

Thanks all.